# Is there any listbox control on the page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I want to learn that in asp.net, 
how can we understand is there any listbox control on the page programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like...

```
if (Page.Controls.OfType<ListBox>().Count() > 0)
   {
       Response.Write("Listbox control exist");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in a Page's control collection recursively

```
int count =0;
private void FindControl(Control Page)

 {


 foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Controls)

 {

      if (ctrl is ListBox)

      {

         count++;
      }

      else 

      {

          if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)

          {

               FindControl(ctrl);

          }

      }

 }

}
```

Comment: how can I check it? Can you give an example please?