# looping through controls on form always getting first control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, webusercontrol

I have a webform which dynamically loads a web user control in it. Within the web user control is a repeater control, and the web user control can be dynamically created within it self as many times as needed, all of these are loaded into a placeholder.

eg:

```
webusercontrol1
   repeater
   webusercontrol
      repeater
   webusercontrol
      repeater
      webusercontrol
         repeater
```

When I loop through the controls within the placeholder, the only repeater that comes up is the first repeater.

my code is as follows:

```
protected void cmdsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach ( Control ctl in this.officephld.Controls )
    {
        if ( ctl.GetType().ToString() == "ASP.evalctl_ascx" )
        {
            foreach ( Control sctl in ctl.Controls )
            { GetRatingControl(sctl); }
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect("~/contractoreval.aspx?sc=1");
}
protected void GetRatingControl(Control item)
{
    Repeater rpt = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rptPts");
    foreach ( Control ctl in rpt.Controls )
    {
        if ( ctl.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem" )
        {
            RepeaterItem ri = (RepeaterItem)ctl;
            HiddenField pntid = (HiddenField)ri.FindControl("pntid");
            HiddenField catid = (HiddenField)ri.FindControl("catid");
            HiddenField rating = (HiddenField)ri.FindControl("rating");
            if ( pntid != null && catid != null )
            {
                AjaxControlToolkit.Rating rtg = (AjaxControlToolkit.Rating)ri.FindControl("pntrating");
                SQLConnectivity db = new SQLConnectivity();
                SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[8];
                int iRetValue = 0;

                param[0] = db.MakeInputParameter("@eval_id", Convert.ToInt32(pntid.Value));
                param[1] = db.MakeInputParameter("@category_id", Convert.ToInt32(catid.Value));
                param[2] = db.MakeInputParameter("@organization_id", 1);
                param[3] = db.MakeInputParameter("@subcontractor_id", 1);
                param[4] = db.MakeInputParameter("@project_id", 1);
                param[5] = db.MakeInputParameter("@rating", Convert.ToInt32(rating.Value));
                param[6] = db.MakeInputParameter("@created_by", 1);
                param[7] = db.MakeInputParameter("@updated_by", 1);
                db.RunNonQueryProcedure("PerformanceSubcontractorEvalSave", param, ref iRetValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT***
for the repeater, this hiddenfield rating is only being instatiated on the first repeat control, the following is my HTML markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPts" runat="server" Visible="false" 
    onitemdatabound="rptPts_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="width:75%;float:left;padding-top:3px;height:20px;">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "eval_description") %>' Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="catid" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="pntid" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="rating" runat="server" />
        <div style="width:20%;float:right;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:3px;height:20px;">
            <cc1:Rating ID="pntrating" runat="server" FilledStarCssClass="filldStar" OnChanged="pntrating_Changed" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyStar" StarCssClass="filldStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedStar" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="false" BehaviorID="ratingControlBehavior">
            </cc1:Rating>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

how can I loop through the various levels of repeater control and get the repeater items within this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't going deep enough into the child controls.

Firstly change this line

`if ( ctl.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem" )`

to this

`if ( ctl is  RepeaterItem )`

as what you have is ugly.

then make a change to GetRatingControl to recursively call itself for each control that is a RepeaterItem.

Comment: I was thinking about doing the recursive, but I am getting stuck on where to perform the recursive.

Comment: ok now does that go inside the IF statement within that loop or after it?

Comment: I tried adding "this.GetRatingControl(ctl);" within the IF statement at the end but I keep getting the same repeat item. If I pass the ctl (which is a repeatitem) it wont work anyway

Comment: Ok got it working however, there is another issue, I am trying to get a hidden control from the repeateritem but on the second repeater control this ("HiddenField rating = (HiddenField)ri.FindControl("rating"); " is coming up null. Why would that be?

Comment: I added an edit to my original posting to maybe help out (it shows my markup for the repeater in HTML

Comment: Sorry mate I am off to bed, its late on Sunday night in New Zealand. My first point of investigation for this problem would be are the other two hiddenfields also coming up null? Put in a breakpoint and take a look at the controls collection on the first and second one and see what is different. I find the immediate window to be quite helpful when doing this sort of thing as you can reasonably easily look at different items in the control collection and there children .

Comment: np mate glad to be of service

Answer (score 0):

please check this question and answer.

Change the condtion to check for a Repeater.

[Check for ListBox inside a page recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200311/is-there-any-listbox-control-on-the-page/7200327#7200327)

Comment: I dont see how that question and answer can really help me as it does not pertain to my question

Comment: @mattgcon. you are just checking a control on form.The link i mentioned is checking for a Listbox. you are checking for a Repeater.The control type is just different.the logic used in both examples are just the same..